# What is the parameter "i" of the set command in the bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell-builtin, set

I looked up the shell builtin command set by typing `help set`, and the short syntax description shows:

> set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]

The help-documentation explains, that the variable $- holds all current parameters set with the set command.

So, I did `echo $-` to display all parameter settings of the shell and mine was:

> himBH

All of the letters are mentioned inside the documentation and the short syntax description from above, but one is missing: the **i** option. What does the `i` `set` parameter mean in bash?

Comment: Related: [Can an interactive shell become non-interactive or vice versa?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/339506)

Answer (score 12):

The `i` there means the shell is interactive.

This is described in [the manpage section](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#INVOCATION) discussing the circumstances in which the shell is interactive:

> An  interactive  shell  is one started without non-option arguments and without the `-c` option whose
>          standard input and error are both connected to terminals  (as  determined  by  `isatty(3)`),  or  one
>          started  with the `-i` option.  `PS1` is set and `$-` includes `i` if `bash` is interactive, allowing a shell
>          script or a startup file to test this state.

The interactive nature of the shell is determined during initialisation, and its effects don’t change during the shell’s lifetime; this is why `set` doesn’t report `i` as a flag that can be altered. In version 4.3 of Bash, `set -i` or `set +i` are accepted, but don’t have any effect beyond altering the `forced_interactive` flag internally (and this flag is only read during initialisation). In version 4.4 they produce an error message. You can see the details of flag handling in [`flags.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/flags.c) in the Bash source code.

Comment: It's probably not listed as an option for `set` as one cannot `set -i` to make an already running shell interactive (`bash` complains with "invalid option").

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, that’s what I thought too.

Comment: what is it good for to type set +i in order to switch the i flag off?

Comment: @sharkant One may test on `$-` to determine if the current shell is interactive or not. This may be useful in shell initialisation scripts. Actually _setting_ this makes no sense as it is determined by the parent process whether it's interactive or not.